# selected value of dropdown list not changing in template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdown list in a template field that has it's selected value on load set to another field in the gridview. In the rowupdating event the dropdown goes back to the initial selected value and does not retain the new value. I have the method that fills the grid wrapped in a if this.page.IsPostBack on the page_load event. How do I bind the control's new selected value during rowupdating event and ignore it's initial databind??

I have the auto post back property set to true as well.

Here is the rowupdating event ( I am actually inserting into a different table NOT updating this grid)

```
protected void grd_add_bins__RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grd_add_bins.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            //int id = Int32.Parse(grdBins.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            Label room1 = (Label)row.FindControl("grd_add_room");
            Label grower1 = (Label)row.FindControl("grd_add_grower_id");
            TextBox bins1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("grd_add_txtbins_to_pack");
            DropDownList packas1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("grd_add_ddl_pack_as");
            TextBox block1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("grd_add_txt_block");
            Label pool1 = (Label)row.FindControl("grd_add_pool");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into t_run_schedule_lots  " +
                              "(record_key,room_id,grower_id,block_id,pool_id,total_bins,pack_as) " +
                              "values (@rec_id,@room,@grower,@block,@pool,@bins,@pack_as)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rec_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblRec_key.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@room", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = room1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@grower", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = grower1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@bins", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(bins1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pack_as", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = packas1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@block", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = block1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pool", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pool1.Text;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
            this.sqlConnection1.Open();
            // execute insert statement
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.sqlConnection1.Close();

            fill_grid();<-- fills other grid that shows the result of the insert
            fill_bins_grid();<-- fills this grid
            //Reset the edit index.
            grd_add_bins.EditIndex = -1;
            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            grd_add_bins.DataBind();



        }
```

Comment: Bind the datagrid in the initial page load. So modify your page load code to use !IsPostBack. Your code is binding the data after every postback.

Comment: OK, so from everything you'v said, the ddl `grd_add_ddl_pack_as` changes value, the page posts back, an insert is done into another table, you re-fill the data tables, and then you re-bind.  But you want `grd_add_ddl_pack_as` to keep its new `Selected` value?  Seems to me that after postback and re-bind it's going to have whatever was returned by `fill_bins_grid` for that record and column as the selected value.

Comment: yes Ann that is correct. But the ddl goes back to the selected value of the field it is binded to.

Comment: I should say that I want the selection of the control to go into the insert statement. But when the event is fired the dropdown goes back to it's bound field value.

Comment: So is there a way to do this??? I have an onindex change event won't work because I can't find the ddl using find control. So in that update event I set the text of a label outside the grid to the selected value. The label changes but not until after the insert is done. Which puts me at square one. There has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a OnSelectedIndexChanged method.

Comment: thats what i was thinking. but I dont know what to do. But if I use that won't I be in the same boat with the post back? Would I just databind that ddl to the new selected value?

Comment: the selected index change event won't fire while until the rowupdating event.

Comment: It should fire. You have to define OnSelectedIndexChanged  where u defined the dropdownlist. and u dont have to call OnSelectedIndexChanged function onb postback. You can save the new selected value in a session and this way you can get the new value.

Comment: The problem is the dropdown is in a template field and tied to the rowupdate event. If I call the dropdown list outside of that event it returns a null reference.